# Как отключить прокрутку экрана при появлении модального окна?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myDialog2");

function showDialog() {
  x.showModal();
}

function closeDialog() {
  x.close();
}
```

```html
<dialog id="myDialog2">
  <div class="f">
    <div class="inbut clearfix">
      <a href="" class="clo" onclick="closeDialog()"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bor2 clearfix">
      <h2>Відновити пароль</h2>
      <input class="container inl" placeholder=" Логин" />
      <div class="inbut j clearfix">
        <a href="#" class="clo2" onclick="closeDialog()">Окей</a>
      </div>
      <p>Повідомлення будет вислано<br/> на ваш Email</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</dialog>

<a id="idp" href="#" onclick="showDialog()" class="link">Вхід</a>
```

Проблема в том, что у меня страницы с скролом и получается, что  модальное окно должно появиться в середине одной из секций, но при его появлении у меня тупо страница на верх скролиться сама, приходить листать вниз, а когда также закрываю модальное окно, оно опять скролиться вверх.
Как убрать этот скрол?

Answer (score 4):

Просто надо дать `body` `overflow:hidden;` когда модальное окно открыто.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myDialog2");

function showDialog() {
  x.showModal();
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';
}

function closeDialog() {
  x.close();
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = 'scroll';
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<dialog id="myDialog2">
  <div class="f">
    <div class="inbut clearfix">
      <a href="" class="clo" onclick="closeDialog()"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bor2 clearfix">
      <h2>Відновити пароль</h2>
      <input class="container inl" placeholder=" Логин" />
      <div class="inbut j clearfix">
        <a href="#" class="clo2" onclick="closeDialog()">Окей</a>
      </div>
      <p>Повідомлення будет вислано<br/> на ваш Email</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</dialog>

<a id="idp" href="#" onclick="showDialog()" class="link">Вхід</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myDialog2");

function showDialog() {
  x.showModal();
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; // Убираем прокрутку
}

function closeDialog() {
  x.close();
  document.body.style.overflow = ''; // Восстанавливаем прокрутку
}
```

```html
<dialog id="myDialog2">
  <div class="f">
    <div class="inbut clearfix">
      <a href="" class="clo" onclick="closeDialog()"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="bor2 clearfix">
      <h2>Відновити пароль</h2>
      <input class="container inl" placeholder=" Логин" />
      <div class="inbut j clearfix">
        <a href="#" class="clo2" onclick="closeDialog()">Окей</a>
      </div>
      <p>Повідомлення будет вислано<br/> на ваш Email</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</dialog>

<a id="idp" href="#" onclick="showDialog()" class="link">Вхід</a>

<div style="height: 1200px"></div>
```